# Белый экран при deploy vite/react на gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, deploy, vite

Обращаюсь так как не смог найти решение на форумах. Выдаёт данные ошибки в консоль:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (index-3d8e5605.css, line 0)

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (index-000e3805.js, line 0)
```

Локально сборка запускается нормально, ts не выдаёт типовых ошибок. В assets на gh-pages branch оба эти файла есть в папке, а так же в dist/ html прописаны линки на эти файлы. Для deploy я использовал файл deploy.sh из документации vite и добавил base в vite.config.ts: "/ArtfulSpaces/" то есть название репозитория. Роуминг тоже пробовал разный Routes/BrowserRouter/HashRouter.

Ссылка на репозиторий:
https://github.com/VRomanenko04/ArtfulSpaces

В чём может быть проблема? Сделал всё, что рекомендовали в ответах, белый экран так же остался, теперь ошибки через раз, то 404, то такие: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в ссылке после билда.
Нужно `base` ссылку в vite.config'e заменить и настройках роутера, вот я как решил эту проблему:

```typescript
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/your-repo-name/' : '/',
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

В вашем случае тут нужно использовать:

`base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/ArtfulSpaces/' : '/',`

Ну и в роутере также нужно задать `base` ссылку

UPD:

Запустив ваш проект у себя локально я получил сообщение что у вас используется вложенный роутер, и я нашел проблему, она в файле App.tsx

Нужно убрать `BrowserRouter` отсюда и применить правило basename в файле `main.tsx`

**App.tsx**

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.NODE_ENV==='production' ? '/ArtfulSpaces' : '/'}>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Layout/>}>
    <Route index element={<Home/>}/>
    ...
    <Route path='howorder' element={<OrderRules/>}/>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

На просто Routes:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Layout/>}>
  <Route index element={<Home/>}/>
  ...
  <Route path='howorder' element={<OrderRules/>}/>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

**main.tsx**

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/ArtfulSpaces' : '/'}>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Сделал все ваши рекомендации, но проблема белого экрана не ушла( я добавил в вопрос как выглядят ошибки.

Comment: Заметьте теперь проблема другая. Скрипты и стили браузер корректно загружает, теперь проблема где-то в другом месте

Comment: Получается проблема не в настройке деплоя, а где-то внутри проекта?

Comment: Да, деплой исправился, но проект локально не будет нормально запускаться. Так как я увидел что вы захардкодили название репозитория что нежелательно делать, ибо не будет корректно работать локально. Вам нужно поставить проверку что это продакшн или локальная сборка, и затем исправить проблемы локально, так как проект не запускается локально.

Comment: Проверил, была проблема по роутингу из-за browserrouter, теперь локально всё работает хорошо, но в продакте всё стало ещё хуже, белый экран остался, а ошибок в логах нету https://vromanenko04.github.io/ArtfulSpaces/

Comment: Вы забыли задать basename в BrowserRouter в [main.tsx](https://github.com/VRomanenko04/ArtfulSpaces/blob/77cf020f048fb5b9aec1d52b135d63c2beb498a3/src/main.tsx#L11C20-L11C20) :) Я обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, и за то, что помогли вне первого вопроса с ошибкой 404) Теперь всё работает

Comment: Пожалуйста) Да вижу, что всё теперь работает корректно :)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключается в том, что `Github Pages` пытается получить `js` и `css` файлы по пути `https://vromanenko04.github.io/assets/index-675017e0.js`, а сама страница у вас находится на `https://vromanenko04.github.io/ArtfulSpaces/` и доступ к `js` файлу можно получить по вот этой ссылке: `https://vromanenko04.github.io/ArtfulSpaces/assets/index-675017e0.js`.

Буквально первый [сайт](https://dev.to/luiszapatayamo/project-deployment-with-reactjs-and-vitejs-in-github-pages-4a7i) по запросу вашей ошибки, предлагает следующее решение (исправлено сразу под ваш случай):

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/ArtfulSpaces/'
})
```

А так же передать `basename` в `BrowserRouter`

```js
<BrowserRouter basename="/ArtfulSpaces">
```

P.s. не увидел, что уже ответ дали, пока я расписывал :( Ну ладно.

Comment: Сделал все ваши рекомендации, но проблема белого экрана не ушла( я добавил в вопрос как выглядят ошибки.

Comment: @ВладимирРоманенко перед деплоем вы еще раз пробовали запустить у себя на локалке проект? Просто ошибка вылетает в самом js файле, почему ошибка происходит не понятно т.к. код обфусцирован, по этому попробуйте у себя на локалке сначала протестировать все ли в порядке.

Comment: Проверил, была проблема по роутингу из-за browserrouter, теперь локально всё работает хорошо, но в продакте всё стало ещё хуже, белый экран остался, а ошибок в логах нету vromanenko04.github.io/ArtfulSpaces

Comment: @ВладимирРоманенко я думаю вам 100% уже помог E1mir. Я хоть так же получал ошибку с BrowserRouter, но почему-то значение ей не предал. Когда я тестил у вас еще был HashRouter и он в какой-то версии React, насколько я помню был разрешен. А в новых уже нет. Может по этому, забил на неё.